# How do I prevent Apache 2.4 from serving files in .git directory?

Tags: apache-2.4, git, httpd.conf

I tried to use an Apache code below in order to prevent serving anything within the `.git` folder. But I can still access to `example.com/.git/config` file.

```
<Directorymatch "^/.*/\.git/">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directorymatch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Deny from all` is the syntax for the older version 2.2 of Apache. The corresponding notation for Apache 2.4 is:

```
Require all denied
```

See [Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html) for more syntax changes.

Comment: Sadly it didn't help.

Comment: Did you restart or reload your apache after removing the `Order` and `Deny` lines? Your regex looks fine, it might be worth trying to remove the trailing slash though.

Comment: Yes, I've edited like [this](https://i.imgur.com/R7leRgs.png) and then I've restarted Apache from the services.

Comment: Well, it worked like this `<Directory "C:/Project/\.git">Require all denied</Directory>`.

Comment: This one is better `<DirectoryMatch "\.git">Require all denied</DirectoryMatch>`.